# How to remove Registry Keys with wildcards

Tags: windows-registry, path, regedit

Are you able to remove a registry key with the following command?

`reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240*" /f`

The asterisk at the end of the path is trying to remove any registry key following after *ECDD91C24*.

If that is not the correct way, what would be the way to remove registry keys that you may not know the last 2 digits of the reg path?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Delete registry key using wildcards](http://serverfault.com/questions/61507/delete-registry-key-using-wildcards).

Answer (score 1):

[**PowerShell**'s registry provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-keys?view=powershell-7.2) allows you to work with registry keys in a manner almost identical to working with files, including using wildcards in paths:

```
PS C:\>>dir hklm:\so*\mi*


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Microsoft
```

[PowerShell's wildcards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) include the familiar `*` and `?`,
as well as `[<list or range>]`:

```
PS C:\>>gci 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\[1,3][5-8]'


    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local
    Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags


Name                           Property
----                           --------
15
16
17
18
35
36
37
38
```

So, the OP would use:

```
del 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240*' -Recurse
```

or more precisely (for GUIDs):

```
ri 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240??}' -Recurse
```

- Without the `-Recurse` parameter, keys with subkeys will display a confirmation message.
- `dir` = `gci` = [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)
- `del` = `ri`  = [Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)

Comment: @G-Man: Thanks for the typo corrections. I try like Hell, but central vision loss makes it hard to see words clearly, regardless of magnification. Fat fingers don't help, eiether! :D

Answer (score 0):

> RegScanner is a small FREE utility that allows you to scan the Registry, find the desired Registry values that match to the specified search criteria, and display them in one list.
>
> Delete Registry Keys and Values with RegScanner
>
> This feature allows you to easily delete unwanted Registry keys and values that you found in the search process. However, in order to decrease the chance of damage from accidental delete action, this feature works as follows:
>
> - Before any delete action, RegScanner will ask you if you want to delete, and the default answer is No.
> - When you delete a value item, only the value is deleted, when you delete a key, the entire key is deleted.
> - A key won't be deleted if it has one or more subkeys.
> - For every delete, the delete values/keys are added into a .bak file located in the folder of RegScanner.exe
> - If RegScanner fails to create the .bak file, it won't delete the selected items.
>
> https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html

Comment: And if the user wants to remove `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, …, `test42`, …, `test_waffle`, etc., by using a wildcard like `test*` — what the question asks for — how does he do that?  This does not answer the question.

Comment: please pay attention to formatting. Don't you see the post is completely messed up? Also remember to use the quote format and give the original link if you're copying texts from somewhere. Click *help* on the comment box or `?` while editing to learn how to use markdown to format properly

Comment: @phuclv if you don't know the answer to the question, blame the questioner... Typical of this website...